# Hex to String Conversion & Use Part of a string

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

Edit: Splitting is working now and I am Converting hex in C# and not in arduino (But if anyone know conversion on arduino side I want to know the solution to convert hex to string on arduino)

I am getting data in Hex on arduino serial monitor,now I want to convert it back to String(how to do this?)
and I wrote a a code for Serial Client in C# where I am receiving the data sent on COM Port & i just want the string from the data I am sending from phone but unable to Separate from that Firmware Version, Found Something! Texts (because they are also coming on COM Port), I want to display Everything in RichTextBox(that is working) but how to just the string we got for other purpose? Data coming on Serial Client is 
`Found chip PN532 
Firmware ver. 1.6
Waiting for Tap!
Found Phone!
68656c6c2079656168`

now I just want to use this hex no for the process ahead in serial client, So how to separate it in C#?

Comment: What are you actually talking about? Splitting the string to get just the last line, or decoding 'hell yeah' from the hex string or...?

Comment: I am able to get hell yeah from the hex but I want to split the last line! In my case it would a hex of random 10 digit No. in the last line and I want to split that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split the data and get the last line, you can simply split it at line delimiters and use Linq to get the last line;

```
var hex = 
  data.Split(new[] {'\n','\r'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

if your string is seperated by `NewLine` character you can split your String using `Environment.NewLine` delimeter.

Try This:

```
var words = str.Split(Environment.NewLine);
var hexNum = words[words.Length-1];
```